# Filling a array of custom objects and returning it in an Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I made a custom class and I'm trying to make an array of objects with it
but I get an error "Object variable or with block variable not set" when I try to add my object to the array.

Macro :

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ArrayLen(arr As Variant) As Integer
    ArrayLen = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1
End Function

Function loadRegisteredFood() As ClsRegisteredFood()
    ' Load all the registered food in memory
    Worksheets("Foods").Activate
    Dim dataRegisteredFood As Range
    Set dataRegisteredFood = Range("RegisteredFoodTable")

    Dim registeredFoods() As ClsRegisteredFood
    ReDim registeredFoods(dataRegisteredFood.Rows.Count - 1)

    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 1 To dataRegisteredFood.Rows.Count
         Dim registeredFood As New ClsRegisteredFood
         registeredFood.Name = dataRegisteredFood.Cells(x, 1).Value
         registeredFood.Prot = dataRegisteredFood.Cells(x, 2).Value
         registeredFood.Fat = dataRegisteredFood.Cells(x, 3).Value
         registeredFood.Carbs = dataRegisteredFood.Cells(x, 4).Value
         registeredFood.Netcarbs = dataRegisteredFood.Cells(x, 5).Value
         registeredFood.Kcal = dataRegisteredFood.Cells(x, 6).Value
         registeredFood.Portion = dataRegisteredFood.Cells(x, 7).Value
         registeredFoods(x - 1) = registeredFood
    Next x

    Dim length As Integer
    length = ArrayLen(registeredFoods)
    MsgBox length

    Dim rf As Variant
    For Each rf In registeredFoods
        MsgBox rf.Name & " contient " & rf.Kcal & " Kcal"
    Next rf

    loadRegisteredFood = registeredFoods
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim registeredFoods() As ClsRegisteredFood
    registeredFoods = loadRegisteredFood()
    ' printRegisteredFood (registeredFoods)
End Sub
```

Class :

```
Public Name As String
Public Prot As Double
Public Fat As Double
Public Carbs As Double
Public Netcarbs As Double
Public Kcal As Double
Public Portion As String
```

The workbook :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jdoa31jo7f1qz85/test.xlsm?dl=0

The error appear on this line `registeredFoods(x - 1) = registeredFood`

What could be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Since the array is an array of objects, you must `Set` the array items `Set registeredFoods(x - 1) = registeredFood`.

Comment: indeed I forgot that, you should put an awser so I can accept it

Comment: @AxelRichter I spoke too fast, in the macro the array contains 14 times the last food line, however in the function the array is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are facing comes because of the missed `Set` in `Set registeredFoods(x - 1) = registeredFood`. Since the array is an array of objects, you must using `Set` for setting the array items.

Also while using `Dim registeredFood As New ClsRegisteredFood` `registeredFood` is **not** a new created `ClsRegisteredFood` object if called multiple times. `Dim` is always only a declaration. It only creates a new object if `registeredFood` is not an object already but is `Nothing`.

The `Dim registeredFood As New ClsRegisteredFood` is the same as

```
Dim registeredFood As ClsRegisteredFood
If registeredFood Is Nothing Then Set registeredFood = New ClsRegisteredFood
```

So you are always overwriting the same object in the for loop.

So do changing your code like:

```
...
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim registeredFood As ClsRegisteredFood
    For x = 1 To dataRegisteredFood.Rows.Count
         Set registeredFood = New ClsRegisteredFood
...
         Set registeredFoods(x - 1) = registeredFood
    Next x
...
```